# Issues in DNS Records

Tags: dns, domain

My Domain is megafollowtwitter.com

I have changed DNS Records in GoDaddy.com

1st Nameserver : ns3779.hostgator.com
2nd Nameserver : ns3780.hostgator.com
Server IP : 50.97.104.98
Now, ns3780.hostgator.com is pointing to domain ip address i.e. 108.167.164.44

What should i do now? Can any one help me?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking.  You've pointed megafollowtwitter.com via the godaddy.com control panel to point to nameservers ns3779.hostgator.com and ns3780.hostgator.com ?  But megafollowtwitter.com is pointing at 108.167.164.44 instead of 50.97.104.98 as it should?  Am I getting that right?

Answer (score 1):

Wait. If you are simply using GoDaddy to redirect your registered domain, you simply need to point the A records for your site to your server's IP address (assuming your server's ports are open and redirecting properly within your network).  You may want to make multiple A records point to the same address as well (for example, www or letmein) so that those subdomains will be redirected.  Otherwise, it simply takes time for the DNS records to propogate throughout the internet.

Comment: Also, as a side note, it should only take a few hours for your domain name to propogate.  Some web hosts will allow you to "resubmit" DNS changes one time within a 24-hour period.  If the changes haven't taken effect by then, you may want to resubmit the changes necessary to your domain host.  I've had to do that on one occassion.